# js - marking bracket pair in input text box depending on cursor position

Tags: javascript, html, brackets, cursor-position, input-field

I'm working on a math project. Therefore I want to modify the 'input text'-Box. It should mark the bracket pair of the cursor i. e. the bracket positioned left and the one right from the cursor.

I already know, how to get the cursor position:

```
document.getElementById('inutField').addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  console.log('pos: + e.target.selectionStart)
})
```

Now I thought about formatting a string

```
str = '3*<span>(</span>4+5<span>)</span>*6
```

formatting the span tag (maybe bold) and put it into the Text field with

```
document.getElementById('inputField').value = str;
```

Unfortunately the value variable doesn't take formatted strings, so it won't work.

Mayby someone has an idea or there is a library that already solves the problem?

Thanx for your help...

Philipp

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/handsontable/formula-parser

Comment: Thank you, for your answer! I think, this is not what I'm searching for... I'm looking for a possibility to format only some of the characters in an input field.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an overkill but you could use one of the WYSIWYG editor libs. The most popular are:

- https://quilljs.com/
- https://ckeditor.com/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).